# Brink - Xbox 360 Controller Support?

Tags: controllers, brink

I just got Brink for PC and was disappointed to find out it does not support the Xbox 360 controller for Windows. I know PC games are intended for Keyboard+Mouse but I cannot sit and use the keys because I get repetitive strain and cramp and whatnot. I use the Xbox 360 Controller for all games when possible.

Anyway, is it possible to use my Xbox 360 Controller on Brink?

Answer (score 2):

Officially there is no controller support for Brink on PC.

*However*, I've found a [thread](http://www.splashdamage.com/forums/showthread.php?t=27506) on the developers forum that describes how to enable Brink to work with an Xbox 360 controller. This requires a console command, and the creation of a `autoexec.cfg` file to manually configure the controller for your needs, so it's not going to be particularly simple, but it's probably your only choice.

I won't repeat all the steps, or `cfg` file, here because of the size (and copyright implications?), but I'd highly recommend visiting the [thread](http://www.splashdamage.com/forums/showthread.php?t=27506) and having a look see if this can help.

Comment: Could not get this to work. I eneded up using the Pinnacle Game Profiler

Comment: @Craig fair enough. But, if you've managed to find something that worked for you, why don't you post that as an answer to your own question so that we can upvote it? :)

Comment: ok how do I answer my own question, do i just edit it?

Comment: @Craig - should be an "answer your own question" button at the bottom (which will pop up a warning), it's intentionally hard to find to discourage people doing it by mistake and clogging up questions with noise.

Comment: There **is** a simpler way that Pinnacle Game Profiler, check this out, it's designed specifically for Brink: http://rush-zone.com/viewdownload/13-brink/22-brinkconfigv15.html

Answer (score 1):

I found a partial solution to this by using the 30-day Trial of a program called Pinnacle Game Profiler.

It still does not feel right but it is better than using the KB+Mouse combination. With some tweaking it may be more useable.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, third party software is not guaranteed to work with all games, but in Brink's case, there is a pretty nice config tool. I like this one, and it has added the option to use an Xbox 360 controller in the latest update, available [here](http://rush-zone.com/viewdownload/13-brink/22-brinkconfigv15.html). (version 1.5)

Answer (score 0):

joy2key can map your keyboard and mouse to a controller anyway you want and it's free.

Comment: The older versions of JoyToKey were free, however the current versions are now shareware.  ([Home](http://www-en.jtksoft.net/))  I haven't tried the latest versions myself yet but as far as I can see, it looks like a lot of the previously missing features are implemented and with better support.